# "React has detected change in order of hooks", but order seems preserved

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
   Previous render            Next render
   ------------------------------------------------------
1. useState                   useState
2. useContext                 useContext
3. useEffect                  useEffect
4. undefined                  useState
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    in ExperienceDetailContainer (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (created by Route)
    in Route (created by withRouter(Connect(ExperienceDetailContainer)))
    in withRouter(Connect(ExperienceDetailContainer)) (created by ExperiencePage)
```

Getting an unexpected error here with hooks. As was my understanding, as long as hooks are called in a predictable order, everything should work fine. A look at my component tells me this is the case, and I cannot understand where the error is originating.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import T from 'prop-types'
import { useWait } from 'react-wait'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import api from 'services/api'
import {
  formattedDateWithoutTime,
  getTimesForCurrentDate
} from 'utils/helpers'
import { fromResource, fromUserSelections, fromSocial } from 'store/selectors'
import {
  resourceDetailReadRequest,
  changeExperienceDate,
  changeExperienceTime,
  updateExperience,
} from 'store/actions'
import { ExperienceDetail, Spinner } from 'components'

const ExperienceDetailContainer = ({
  detail,
  readDetail,
  experienceDate,
  changeExperienceDate,
  experienceTime,
  changeExperienceTime,
  adults,
  kids,
  updateExperience,
  user,
  ...props
}) => {
  const [error, setError] = useState('')
  const { startWaiting, endWaiting } = useWait()

  useEffect(() => {
    readDetail(apiRequestParams)
    getExperienceAvailabilities()
  }, [])

  const experienceId = props.match.params.experienceid
  const cityId = props.match.params.cityid

  const apiRequestParams = {
    endpoint: "GetExperienceInfo",
    experienceid: experienceId,
    adults,
    kids
  }

  const availableStartTimes = getTimesForCurrentDate(experienceDate, detail.availabilities)

  const getExperienceAvailabilities = () => {
    api.post('/GetExperienceAvailabilities', {
      experienceid: experienceId
    })
    .then(result => {
      const availabilities = result.d
      updateExperience(availabilities)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err)
    })
  }

  if (!detail.experienceid) {
    return <Spinner />
  }

  return <ExperienceDetail
    loading={!detail.experienceid}
    {...{
      detail,
      error,
      experienceId,
      availableStartTimes,
      changeExperienceDate,
      experienceDate,
      changeExperienceTime,
      experienceTime,
      getQuoteBooking,
  }}/>
}

ExperienceDetailContainer.propTypes = {
  detail: T.object.isRequired,
  changeExperienceDate: T.func.isRequired,
  experienceDate: T.instanceOf(Date),
  changeExperienceTime: T.func.isRequired,
  experienceTime: T.string,
  adults: T.number.isRequired,
  kids: T.number.isRequired,
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  user: fromSocial.getUser(state),
  detail: fromResource.getDetail(state, 'experience'),
  experienceDate: fromUserSelections.getDate(state),
  experienceTime: fromUserSelections.getTime(state),
  adults: fromUserSelections.getAdults(state),
  kids: fromUserSelections.getAdults(state),
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  readDetail: (apiRequestParams) => dispatch(resourceDetailReadRequest('experience', { apiRequestParams })),
  changeExperienceDate: (experienceDate) => dispatch(changeExperienceDate(experienceDate)),
  changeExperienceTime: (experienceTime) => dispatch(changeExperienceTime(experienceTime)),
  updateExperience: (availabilities) => dispatch(updateExperience('experience', availabilities))
})

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ExperienceDetailContainer))
```

As can be seen, I am using 3 hooks: useState, useWait, useEffect. They are all called at the top level, and not in conditionals or anything that would compromise order.

Am I having some fundamental misunderstanding here?

Comment: a lot of code for people to look at! Did you ever find an answer? I have a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of hooks usage is correct and the most likely issue is that your `getTimesForCurrentDate` function is using `useState` hook conditionally.

React's message matches your usage of hooks - `useWait` internally uses `useContext` and React is able to list only its own hooks, that's why there is `useState`, `useContext` (not `useWait`), `useEffect`. And that function is the only thing that gets executed within render after your `useEffect` registration.

PS: Technically, it could also happen if you have property getter in one of props.match.params.cityid, ..., keys and use `useState` hook conditionally there, but that feels like really bad idea ;-).